# replicating times across set of dates in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to take the following series of times...and replicate them for the next set of dates...

i.e.

```
9/1/13 10:00
9/1/13 13:00
9/1/13 16:00
9/1/13 19:05
9/1/13 22:00
```

And make it a list of cells that shows the same for 9/1 to 9/30

```
9/1/13 10:00
9/1/13 13:00
9/1/13 16:00
9/1/13 19:05
9/1/13 22:00
9/2/13 10:00
9/2/13 13:00
9/2/13 16:00
9/2/13 19:05
9/2/13 22:00
```

Is there a better way than doing this manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to do this once, you can try this:

First, put in the data for 9/1 as you have.

Then enter this formula into the next cell (assuming data starts in A1):

```
=A1+1
```

Then select that cell with the formula and drag the formula down until you reach 9/30/2013 22:00 (row 150 if data starts in A1)

Then, copy all of the data and Paste Special->Values Only into the same range.